# rails include with array of id on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, orm

I tried to find with array of value using where condition and includes.
But gettting some error..

the below works well and return beneficiary with user included

```
Beneficiary.includes(:user).where("beneficiaries.id = ?",304)
```

but when i try with array of ID i'm getting some error

```
Beneficiary.includes(:caterer_info).where("beneficiaries.id = ?",[304,305])

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '304,305)'
```

Comment: might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947593/how-to-use-in-1-2-3-with-findall

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
Beneficiary.includes(:caterer_info).where({beneficiaries: {id: [304,305]}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try with `where` method instead of `find_all_by_id`

```
Beneficiary.includes(:caterer_info).where('beneficiaries.id IN (?)', [304,305])
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer on my own

```
   Beneficiary.includes(:user).where("beneficiaries.id IN (?)",ids)
```

Thanks